# Pass 'void' as a function parameter

Tags: c++, function, templates, parameters, void

I have a function which should accept a parameter of any type. Therefore I use templates.

```
template <typename T>
void Function(T Parameter);
```

The function calls a function. In my real application, there is a map of callbacks with string keys, but that doesn't matter for this question. The callback must be a function pointer with return type *void*, but any parameter type.

```
void* Callback;

template <typename T>
void Function(T Parameter)
{
    (function<void(T))Callback(Parameter);
}
```

Assuming that the callback is of the right type, this should work like the following.

```
Function<int>(42);

// should result in...
(function<void(int))Callback(42);
```

But in some cases I want to pass `void` as parameter.

```
Function<void>(void);

// should result in...
(function<void(void)>Callback(void);
```

As you can see, I need to provide nothing or `void` as a parameter. But I cannot pass `void` as argument. There is an error that the typename would be incorrect.

How can I pass `void` as an function argument?

Comment: There's probably `boost` for that, but what would happen if you just wrote `function<void()>`?

Comment: You should have a variadic template, like `template <typename ...Args> void Function(Args...)`. We discussed this a couple of days ago; search around.

Comment: Sounds like a job for template specialization. Unfortunately, it's not supported for out of class funcs

Comment: @Bartek. How could I now if the template type is void to use your line?

Comment: @icepack. The function is inside a class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just specify a non-template overload:

```
void* Callback;

template <typename T>
void Function(T Parameter)
{
    (function<void(T)>)Callback(Parameter);
}

void Function()
{
    (function<void()>)Callback();
}
```